# is it Possible to Add Button in Antd Modal header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

Created Modal in antd now need to add custom button in the header part of the Modal, tried some approaches but didn't succeed.

Comment: Provide code that you already tried and clarify your question please, it's not clear what you really want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Modal title={<button>abc</button>} visible={isModalVisible}>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
    <p>Some contents...</p>
  </Modal>
```